# How to set Mudblazor DataGrid colum width

Tags: datagrid, blazor, mudblazor

Trying to set the column widths of a MudBlazor DataGrid can be a pain. For some reason setting the style via **CellClass** or **HeaderClass** or **CellStyle** or **HeaderStyle** of Column did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the  tag solved the problem:

````
    <ColGroup>
        <col style="width: 20%;" />
        <col style="width: 10%;" />
        <col style="width: 20%;" />
        <col style="width: 20%;"/>
        <col />
    </ColGroup>
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>```
````